# How to normalize a GridView across multiple devices?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Consider the following example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  const project = MaterialApp(
    home: HomeScreen(),
  );

  runApp(project);
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  Widget simpleGridView() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisSpacing: 12,
        crossAxisSpacing: 12,
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: simpleGridView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you observe the design output on both Android and iOS, you will notice a nice consistency on the spacing when `SafeArea` is being used. However, as soon as you remove `SafeArea` from the design equation, an inconsistency on the spacing will be observed. That is, an extra margin on top and bottom will be added for iOS. But for Android, only a top margin will be added.

How can this issue be fixed to guarantee design consistency across multiple devices?

Screenshots for both Android and iOS when `SafeArea` is part of the design:

[image]
[image]

Screenshots for both Android and iOS when `SafeArea` is **NOT** part of the design:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Simply remove SafeArea widget

Comment: @DarshanKachhadiya fine but, how do you fix the spacing inconsistency as a result of removing the SafeArea widget?